# virtualenv hung up on installing setuptools

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, powershell, virtualenv

never had this issue until just recently, but when trying to create a new virtual environment (windows 7, python 2.7.13, virtualenv==15.1.0) it just hangs on "Installing setuptools, pip, wheel..." and doing a crtl^c gives you this:

```
PS C:\Users\John\Envs> virtualenv.exe rmapvenv
New python executable in C:\Users\John\Envs\test\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 769, in call_subprocess
    line = stdout.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

adding some print statements in virtualenv.py gives me this:

```
Running command C:\Users\John\Envs\test\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel

Collecting setuptools

  Using cached setuptools-35.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Collecting pip

Collecting wheel
```

it seems to be hung up on wheel

Comment: As far as I can tell, this just suggests that the program is waiting on output from a command it has called. `call_subprocess` takes a command (as `cmd`) and executes it, and reads the stdout of that process. You can see here it's waiting on a full line to be written. Could you try running this inside a debugger and getting the value of `cmd`, which should indicate the subprocess that's really hanging.

Comment: updated the original question with more details.

Comment: Hi John try to create the virtualenv giving to this the executable python path like this:
`virtualenv --python=C:\Python27\python.exe env`
I'm using windows 10 virtualenv 13, but I don't think this matter

Comment: yields the same results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up environment in virtaulenv using python3 stuck on setuptools, pip, wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674311/setting-up-environment-in-virtaulenv-using-python3-stuck-on-setuptools-pip-whe)

Answer (score 14):

Use the `-v` switch to get Verbose output.

For me, it was a network connection. Specifically, the server I was trying to use `virtualenv` on was firewalled from the Internet and I needed to get out thru a proxy. Except, that virtualenv doesn't seem to honor the proxy settings in the environment and it has no commandline switch.

So use `pip` to pre-cache/pre-download the 3 needed packages:

`sudo pip download setuptools pip wheel --proxy http://<yourproxyhere>`

Then you can run `virtualenv` and it will use the cached packages that you just downloaded.

Answer (score 6):

I was using pipenv to install a venv :

```
$ pipenv install
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: /home/seba/Sources/neogeo/grandlyon/photon-setup/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.6.7) to create virtualenv…
⠦ Creating virtual environment...
```

Verbose mode didn't give me more information, `--clear` was useless but using `ps auxf`, I saw the python process was waiting for nothing:

```
 [...] S+   09:59   0:00  |   |       \_ /home/seba/Sources/[...]/venv/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel
```

It stalled installing setuptools.

Creating a virtualenv as usual confirmed me this:

```
$ virtualenv -vv --python=python3 venv
[...]
Running command /home/seba/Sources/n...tup/venv/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel
Looking in links: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/virtualenv_support
Collecting setuptools
[Waiting forever]
```

The fix was dropping pip cache:

```
$ rm -Rf ~/.cache/pip/ ~/.cache/pip-tools/
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well and none of the answers above worked.  Turned out to be a bad cache entry.

With `$ virtualenv -vv venv` I'd get output ending with:

```
Running command /Users/ghartmann/cod...test/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel
Collecting setuptools
    Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
```

It would block there and then when you interrupted you'd see the stack indicating it was blocked downloading the `wheel` package.

On macos the pip cache is here: `~/Library/Caches/pip`.
Removing that directory fixed the issue, as it was able to reinitialize the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Everything seemed to revolve around wheel not installing, so if someone can explain this, please do. this is what I did to get it to install. I ran:

```
virtualenv venv --no-wheel
```

then, activated my virtual environment and ran:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install setuptools --no-use-wheel --upgrade
pip install wheel --no-cache
```

and as far as I can tell, everything works

Answer (score 1):

I was behind a corporate firewall using `pipenv`.  Even though the `Pipfile` was pointing to our local package index (not PyPi), the `pip` that `pipenv` called was still trying to use PyPi and hanging at

```
/home/eric/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel
```

The solution for me was to either set the index URL in `pip.conf` or use the `PIP_INDEX_URL` environment variable, for example:

```
PIP_INDEX_URL=http://my.corporate.index/simple pipenv lock
```

Comment: I wasn't behind a firewall but had Open VPN running. Turned it off and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help but I had the exact same problem, albeit on linux debian (raspbian Jessie light to be precise) and python 3.6. Wheel hanged upon creating a virtualenv, and I got the same error messages as you after a ctrl-c (with python 3.6 and linux paths). I then had unnoticed internet connection problems, after solving these, wheel installed properly.